# Prove that you can find two planes, each containing a separate line, that never intersect given that the two lines are skew

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vectors

In my Calculus 3 class, we were given two lines L1 and L2 in the form $\begin{align*}\vec r & = \left\langle {{x_0},{y_0},{z_0}} \right\rangle  + t\vec v\end{align*}$
and told to find the distance between two planes, each plane containing one of the lines. To solve this problem, I observed that taking the cross product of the two line vectors, $\vec v_1\times \vec v_2$, gives a normal vector $\vec n$   which, when put into two plane equations each containing a point $P(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ on either line, creates two planes which never intersect, each containing one of the lines. You can then find the distance between these two planes to get the answer.

My question is, does this method work with any skew set of two lines? If so, how can this be proven? I understand that two planes with the same normal vector are parallel, but am still confused on how to prove that a good normal vector can be found for any skew line set.

Comment: Unless the lines are parallel the cross product method works for any non-intersecting lines.

Comment: I think I can understand why that method wouldn't work if they are parallel. However, I'm looking more for a proof that this method works for non-parallel, non-intersecting lines.

Comment: i don't see what you want.  Your original description applies for non-parallel lines..  Cross product of normal with each line define the planes.  For parallel lines the cross product = 0.

Comment: Essentially I'm curious to know if there's proof that two skew lines can always generate two planes which never intersect. I know they do, but I'm curious about a proof for this.

Comment: I don't understand what you are looking for.  My previous note describes the essential proof.  The net result is a pair of parallel planes, each containing one of the lines.